# R function to aggregate all elements in a list

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

Using the tidyverse package, I can easily aggregate a single variable. However, I wish to create a function which will allow me to aggregate multiple variables simultaneously.

I understand I have to convert the dataframe containing multiple variables to a list and then lapply an aggregating function across this list. However, I am unable to create this function.

Following is a REPREX of what I am trying to do:

```
# Load package

library(dplyr)

# Load dataset

dat <- data.frame(Titanic)

# Select variables

dat <- dat[, c('Class', 'Sex', 'Age','Survived')]

# Aggregate a single variable

dat %>% group_by(Class) %>% summarise(n=n())
        
# Desired outcome: Aggregate all variables simultaneously using a function

dat_ls <- as.list(dat)                       ## Create a list with all the variables
dat_agg <- lapply(dat_ls, function(???))     ## Apply aggregating function to each element in the list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `list`, we can use `table`

```
lapply(dat_ls, table)
```

---

Another option is to reshape to 'long' format and then use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
   count(name, value)
```

Comment: how do i put the aggregating steps into a function which can be used in laaply? creating the function is the main thing i am seeking an answer to

Comment: @kyg what you have done with `dat %>% group_by(Class) %>% summarise(n=n())` is the same you are doing with `table`.  The `dat_ls` is a list of vectors.  If you want a function, `f1 <- function(x) table(x)` and then use `lapply(dat_ls, f1)`